# ajax issue in jsf form: malformedXML: During update

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

Please I need your support to resolve this ajax issue.
I'm using Jsf 2.1, CDI Bean, Hibernate.
I have a problem when putting `<f:ajax render="@form" />` in my form.
I have a select box, I want to Hide/Show form depending on selectOneMenu value change.
after selecting the value, this issue is displayed as mentioned in the image attached.In addition. how could I resolve it please. 
[attached images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFVqU.png)

Comment: JSF2.1 is an api 'version'... What concrete version and implementation are you using? 2.1.x where x is? And did you try [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=viewstate+ajax+jsf+2.1+problem)

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.7</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.7</version>
  </dependency>